# Is there a Python Version of Cardano Node-CLI JavaScript Library?

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node, javascript, python

I know JS, but I have other code written in python that I want to use in conjunction with the node. Is there a Python 3.xxxx SDK/Library/Module that will do everything the JS can?

Heres what is written about the JS Version: https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/cardanocli-js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know you are asking for a python library interacting with a node, but let me tell you there is a very comprehensive python library with which you don't need to run a node yourself.

You can find a list of it's features in the README https://github.com/cffls/pycardano/

For completeness, there are a few python libraries wrapping a cardano node and interacting with the cli. I haven't used any of those and I am not sure what features they support exactly, but here you go:

- https://github.com/emesik/cardano-python
- https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-clusterlib-py
- https://gitlab.com/viper-staking/cardano-tools